# Puppeteer. Открыть браузер на втором (дополнительном) мониторе

Tags: puppeteer

Как открыть браузер на втором (дополнительном) мониторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого необходимо воспользоваться параметром `--window-position=x, y`;
При этом, нужно учесть местоположение второго экрана. Если экран находится выше основного, то `х` и `y` значение могут иметь знак `-`

```
const options = {
  devtools: true,
  headless: false,
  args: ['--window-size=1920,1070', '--window-position=-310,-1080']
};

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
```